# UIWebView won't resize to fit content?

Tags: iphone, uiweb

My webView is not resizing properly after it finished loading. I have tried this code.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview {
    CGRect frame = webView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    frame.size.width = screenWidth;
    webView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    webView.frame = frame;
    [bodyScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(screenWidth, webView.frame.origin.y + webView.frame.size.height+keyboardRectY+60)];
```

It is incresing the width beyond the screenWidth and hence my content horizontally expands beyond the view size which I don't want.

changing

```
CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(screenWidht, 1)];
```

also leads to the same situation.

How can I get rid of this? The webview width should always remain as screenwidth and only it's height should adjust based on the content size so that the webView just about fits the whole content.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have a look at this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922731/uiwebview-doesnt-seem-to-be-loading-the-page) Search SO for autoresizingmask UIWebView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting the size of `frame`, you are overwriting the width you set previously. This should it:

```
...
CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
fittingSize.width = screenWidth; // Add this
frame.size = fittingSize
...
```

Comment: This sets the frame OK but my text still doesn't wrap to screenWidth but expands horizontally beyond the screenWidth. Why?

Comment: I have the same problem. Why did you select this answer as the correct answer when it really isn't the correct solution?